# c# System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException when calling System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction.Commit()

Tags: c#, exception, synchronization, message-queue

My code reads transactional messages from a message queue. The code has run thousands and thousands of messages and all of a sudden when I commit one of the previously read messages an exception is thrown. The commit is performed on a different thread than the thread that is reading messages, which to my opinion should not be a problem. The documentation about transactions does not tell me to synchronize the commit nor the abort method with some object. This exception is related to using a monitor, but I ain't using one, the underlying framework code might do so but that is outside my control.

I used to have this exception occasionally when I did a timed read on the message queue, I have rewritten the code so that It uses an async peek first to check if there is data to be read. This way I circumvented the exception occurring. but now it's back again.

Please help me in how I can avoid this exception, or is this a bug in the c# framework underlying code?

Regards Martien

```
// Part of thread code that reads transaction
transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
transaction.Begin();
message = _ItfSureStoreInstance.MQSet.MQ_Retry.mqueue.Receive(transaction);

// We have data received
DataImplementation<TMessage> dataRxd = new DataImplementation<TMessage>(this,message,transaction,true);
```

Comment: What is the exact exception message? And is there an InnerException?

Comment: System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction.Commit() and there is no innerexception

Comment: That's weird. Shouldn't you be using the transaction in a using block? An extra thread for commiting surely complicates that pattern.

Comment: The part that reads a transaction creates a new object

transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();   
transaction.Begin();

message = _ItfSureStoreInstance.MQSet.MQ_Retry.mqueue.Receive(transaction);

// We have data received
DataImplementation<TMessage> dataRxd = new DataImplementation<TMessage>(this,message,transaction,true);


then a callback is called which places the object on a queue for further processing. At some point in time the transaction is commited.

Comment: I thinks the pattern is straightforward. transaction new, begin and then commit/Abort. Like most database transactions act. Maybe I can lock the transaction and than commit, but by not knowing the exact problem it is just guessing for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeuetransaction.aspx is documented fairly well.  It details that this can't be used on a single threaded apartment (STA) thread.  Winforms applications must be STA on the main (UI) thread.  This means using `MessageQueueTransaction` from a WinForm (or a default Console application main thread) is not supported (i.e. it will fail occaisionally).

The recommended way of using `MessageQueueTransaction` is to do it from a new, MTA, thread.  You can do this with `new Thread` or you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: The thread I'm using to read messages from the queue and committing on are both created with "new Thread" and are not communicating with a UI thread or the like. So this is exactly what I'm doing and does not explain my occasional exception. So this does not explain my problem. Sorry.

Comment: Also the documentation mentions that I would suffer from a messagequeueException and that is not what happens. See subject. Thanks for trying to help. But it is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Martien does ensuring the thread that uses `MessageQueueTransaction` is on an MTA thread resolve the issue?  There might be a bug in `MessageQueueTransaction` that doesn't check for STA property and gets `lock`s out of sync.  But, I'm guessing at root cause.

Comment: As stated earlier the thread that is reading and the thread that is committing are both created with a call to new System.Threading.Thread. If this assures by default that this implies creating a MTA type thread than this is not the problem.